# Export Access database to existing excel doc using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So after searching through numerous other pages im still having difficulty and admittedly its due to self teaching myself VBA, so forgive me :(

I have created a simple Phone call counter Access form with a table. My goal is to press a button and it exports the table to a specified directory to an existing XLSM (the data exported would open a new worksheet with the current date as the worksheet name and then save it.

database location is here:
L:\Reports\TestCalltoolmetric.accdb

existing Excel file is here:
L:\Reports\Callcounterreports\MonthlyCallCounter.xlsm

What i have tried so far...

1.

```
Dim strTable As String 
Dim strWorksheetPath As String
strWorksheetPath = "L:\Reports\Callcounterreports"
strWorksheetPath = strWorksheetPath & Format(Date, "ddmmmyy") & "Callreport.xlsx"
```

This exports my database to a new file with the name of the file as the date+callreport. It works but i dont know if i can use this command to accomplish my goal above (filename isnt really important but at the end of the month i need to provide call metrics so i need every days export all in one workbook so i can create totals).

2.
I tried using this:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Table1", "L:\Reports\Callcounterreports\MonthlyCallCounter.xlsm"
```

But it errors out saying that Access database engine could not find the object 'Table1'

3.
I also found through some furious googling a similar request but it was based off exporting a query...in an less than educated mannor i tried adapting it but never really was able to get it to work..

```
Dim appXL As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim wks As Object
Dim xlf As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

xlf = "L:\Reports\Callcounterreports\MonthlyCallCounter.xlsm" 'Full path to Excel file

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query1") 'Replace Query1 with real query name
Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = appXL.Workbooks.Open(xlf)
Set wks = wb.Sheets & Format (Date, "ddmmmyy") ' Sheet name


wb.Save
wb.Close
appXL.Quit
Set wb = Nothing
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

I know i am by far not the first person to probably ask about how to do this, but any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Going through this i feel like i have the start of the solutions, i just cant find the pieces im missing

Comment: Error message is telling you exactly what th eproblem is "could not find the object 'Table1'" - put in the correct table name

Comment: Is "Table1" the worksheet name, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

SO....after futher digging i figured out what i was doing wrong with at least using

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Table1", "L:\Reports\Callcounterreports\MonthlyCallCounter.xlsm"

I first had to rename the table from "Table1" to another name, which i chose "DataTable".
Second i made a mistake on the filepath portion of the command, the location was a networked location which showed up a drive letter. after putting the full and correct file path the form worked like a charm.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access
i used this website to verify my commands, which now i feel silly that i hadnt found it before.
Big thank you to @dbmitch i think frustration got the better of me instead of really reading the error info..